# Why is my GoTo function not working properly

Tags: excel, vba

My GoTo is not jumping onto Reve: but it is jumping on Gen:. I don't know why it's not working. The problem is when I input the 41010020 in the cell C22, it just clears the cells that are called in the Reve:. It does not go on Reve:. I think the logic in my code is right but I don't know why it's not working.

```
Sub ValidateCode2()
Dim sto As String, cod As String, rev As String, cog As String, dis As String, brandlist As String, prodlist As String
Dim codres As String, revres As String, cogres As String, disres As String, stores As String
Dim brandresult As String, prodresult As String
Dim i As Long, x As Long
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook


sto = wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("C26").Value
cog = wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("F22").Value
rev = wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("C22").Value
dis = wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("F23").Value
cod = wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("C18").Value
brandlist = wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("C19").Value
prodlist = wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("D19").Value


If wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("C22").Value = 41010020 Then GoTo Reve Else


For i = 2 To 13
    If sto = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("B" & i).Value Then codres = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("D" & i).Value
Next

For i = 2 To 13
    If sto = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("B" & i).Value Then revres = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("E" & i).Value
Next

For i = 2 To 13
    If sto = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("B" & i).Value Then cogres = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("F" & i).Value
Next

For i = 2 To 13
    If sto = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("B" & i).Value Then disres = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("G" & i).Value
Next

'Brand
For i = 2 To 5000
    If brandlist = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("P" & i).Value Then brandresult = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("Q" & i).Value
Next

'Product
For i = 2 To 32
    If prodlist = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("U" & i).Value Then prodresult = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("V" & i).Value
Next
GoTo Gen

Reve:
'Brand
For i = 2 To 5000
    If brandlist = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("P" & i).Value Then brandresult = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("Q" & i).Value
Next

'Product
For i = 2 To 32
    If prodlist = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("U" & i).Value Then prodresult = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("V" & i).Value
Next
wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("C18").Value = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("D3").Value + prodresult + brandresult
wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("C22").Value = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("E3").Value
wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("F22").Value = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("F3").Value
wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("F23").Value = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("G3").Value
wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("C26").Value = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("B3").Value

Gen:
wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("C18").Value = codres + prodresult + brandresult
wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("C22").Value = revres
wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("F22").Value = cogres
wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("F23").Value = disres

End Sub
```

Comment: Note: It's better to not use `GoTo`. That creates spaghetti code. As mentioned in a comment on one of your previous questions, what exactly are you trying to do? This can be probably done much more simply - for one, those loops are repetitive and I'm not sure you need a loop anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to look at BigBen's comment on spaghetti code, because with this structure, it quickly becomes convuluted...

I think the problem you have can be traced to the IF THEN structure.

You need to rewrite it in several lines like this:

```
If wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("C22").Value = 41010020 Then
    GoTo Reve
Else
...
End if
```

Otherwise it produces an error code... did you get an error code?